# How to specify block size when formatting?

Tags: usb, ntfs, format

I need to format a 4 GB Pendrive with blocks size of 4 KB in NTFS format type.

I understand that I can do `mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1` to give NTFS format.

But is there any way (parameter or something like this) in which I could specify the block size that I want?

Answer (score 2):

type in Terminal:

```
mkntfs -c 4096 /dev/sdb1
```

from mkntfs man page:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mkntfs.8.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe that NTFS refers to blocks as 'clusters'. With that in mind, `mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1 -c 4096` should do what you're looking for. This is the default size, however, so strictly speaking unnecessary!